# Implementing fancy indexing in a class

Tags: python

Some libraries like numpy, pandas or even python lists implement fancy indexing for its objects. This means I can do things like:

```
obj[1:3, :]
```

If I want to offer this functionality in my class I could try to overload the `__getitem__` and the `__setitem__` methods:

```
class Example(object):
   def __getitem__(self, x):
      pass
```

but I don't see how this could work as `1:3` is not a valid variable name. How can this functionality be achieved?

Comment: It's called `__getitem__`, not `__get_item__` (and likewise `__setitem__`).

Comment: you are right, fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing special about the slice notation is the shorthand for `slice`, which makes your code equivalent to:

```
obj[(slice(1, 3), slice(None, None))]
```

The parameter passed to `__getitem__` is the "index" of the item, which can be any object:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    if isinstance(index, tuple):
        # foo[1:2, 3:4]
    elif isinstance(index, slice)
        # foo[1:2]
    else:
        # foo[1]
```

Answer (score 7):

Slices like `1:3` are turned into [`slice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) objects and passed to your function. If you have multiple indexers, they are turned into a [`tuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple). To demonstrate:

```
>>> class Example(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, index):
...         return index
... 
>>> example = Example()
>>> example['hello']
'hello'
>>> example[1:5]
slice(1, 5, None)
>>> example[1:5, 10:15]
(slice(1, 5, None), slice(10, 15, None))
```